# How to search by non-tokenized field length in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

Say I create an index **people** which will take entries that will have two properties: **name** and **friends**

```
PUT /people
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "friends": { 
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": { 
            "type": "keyword"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and I put two entries, each one of them has two friends.

```
POST /people/_doc
{
  "name": "Jack",
  "friends": [
    "Jill", "John"
  ]
}


POST /people/_doc
{
  "name": "Max",
  "friends": [
    "John", "John"  # Max will have two friends, but both named John
  ]
}
```

Now I want to search for people that have multiple friends

```
GET /people/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "script": {
            "script": {
              "source": "doc['friends.keyword'].length > 1"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

This will only return **Jack** and ignore **Max**. I assume this is because we are actually traversing the inversed index, and John and John create only one token - which is 'john' so the length of the tokens is actually 1 here.

Since my index is relatively small and performance is not the key, I would like to actually traverse the source and not the inversed index

```
GET /people/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "script": {
            "script": {
              "source": "ctx._source.friends.length > 1"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

But according to the https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/20068 the source is supported only when updating, not when searching, so I cannot.

One obvious solution to this seems to take the length of the field and store it to the index. Something like **friends_count: 2** and then filter based on that. But that requires reindexing and also this appears as something that should be solved in some obvious way I am missing.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a new feature in ES 7.11 as runtime fields a runtime field is a field that is evaluated at query time. Runtime fields enable you to:

1. Add fields to existing documents without reindexing your data
2. Start working with your data without understanding how it’s structured
3. Override the value returned from an indexed field at query time
4. Define fields for a specific use without modifying the underlying schema

you can find more information [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.11/runtime.html) about runtime fields, but how you can use runtime fields you can do something like this:

**Index Time:**

```
PUT my-index/
{
  "mappings": {
    "runtime": {
      "friends_count": {
        "type": "keyword",
        "script": {
          "source": "doc['@friends'].size()"
        }
      }
    },
    "properties": {
      "@timestamp": {"type": "date"}
    }
  }
}
```

You can also use runtime fields in search time for more information check [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.11/runtime-search-request.html).

**Search Time**

```
GET my-index/_search
{
  "runtime_mappings": {
    "friends_count": {
      "type": "keyword",
      "script": {
        "source": "ctx._source.friends.size()"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Update:**

```
POST mytest/_update_by_query
{
    "query": {
        "match_all": {}
    }, 
    "script": {
       "source": "ctx._source.arrayLength = ctx._source.friends.size()"
    }
}
```

You can update all of your document with query above and adjust your query.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer. Although I think that script_fields or runtime_mappings are likely the way to go to solve similar problems, I did not manage to utilize it to solve the problem. I think it is impossible as source is probably created after the query is done, so I think its impossible filter the query based on non-tokenized field length (unless done on the app level). But maybe I am missing something.

Comment: I updated my answer for generating new field and update all your document to add it.

Comment: yeah that is also a way to go. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

For everyone wondering about the same issue, I think @Kaveh answer is the most likely way to go, but I did not manage to make it work in my case. It seems to me that source is created after the query is performed and therefore you cannot access source for the purposes of filtering query.

This leaves you with two options:

- filter the result on the application level (ugly and slow solution)
- actually save the filed length in a separate field. Such as **friends_count**

possibly there is another option I don't know about(?).